# Getting No data when accessing SAP table with JCo 3.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, jco

Here is my sample code. In this example has only elementary types, no structure types has to set. But in the output no data exists in the table.

When I check the records in SAP table it contains multiple records for this particular id. Can someone explain this to me?

```
public void invokeRFC(JCoDestination destination) {

    JCoFunction function=null;
    try

    {
        JCoFunctionTemplate functionTemplate = destination.getRepository().getFunctionTemplate("RFC_METHOD");

        if (functionTemplate != null) {
            function = functionTemplate.getFunction();
        }

        if (function == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Not found in SAP.");

        //to fill elementary types and structures
        configureImportParameters(function,"xxx",  "abc");
        //to fill table type parameters
        configureTableParameters(function, "tblName",1,"100");
        function.execute(destination);


    } catch (JCoException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void configureTableParameters(JCoFunction function, String table_name, int index, String id) {
    JCoTable table = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("table_name");

    table.appendRow();
    table.setRow(index);
    table.setValue("Partner", "100");

}

private void exportTable(JCoFunction jCoFunction, String tblName) {
    JCoTable resultTable = jCoFunction.getTableParameterList().getTable(tblName);

    int value = resultTable.getNumRows();
    System.out.println(value);
}

private void configureImportParameters(JCoFunction function, String param1, String param2) {

    JCoParameterList parameterList = 
    function.getImportParameterList();
    parameterList.setValue("field1", param1);
    parameterList.setValue("field2", param2);

}
```

Comment: any error you are getting or it's just that row count is 0? If later is the case, execute RFC on SAP side and check count, and make sure parameters are same

Comment: I'm getting partner 100 doesn't exists message in the export RETTEXT value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple problem can cause this.

1. if you setting "" or " " to  fields. (when you set values better set if those has some values
2. if it says partner does not exist and if you sure its exist this mean your data does not pass properly. add debug points to where you set the data and make sure you pass correct name and correct values.
3. also you do not need to add(index) you can just table.appendRow(); // but this will not impact on your case
4. also when you setValue make sure its int filed. (normally not) in your given example its int

eg:

```
private void configureTableParameters(JCoParameterList tableParameters){
    JCoTable jCoTable=tableParameters.getTable(key);
    jCoTable.appendRow();
    if(value!=null)
    jCoTable.setValue(fieldKey,String.valueOf(value));

}
```

this is just psuda code and will not work

Comment: Yes,I found the issue.As you mentioned above in my code I set "" values to import parameters  suppose to be empty. Now it's working as expected. :)

Comment: @cat1197: In the code fragment from your question post you do _not_ set "" values to the import parameters. You are setting values "xxx" and "abc". If you are doing different things than described in your question, you will usually **not** get appropriate help here.

Comment: @Krishantha Dinesh: Always calling the String based setValue([name|index], java.lang.String)-method is not necessary. JCo does appropriate data type conversions from and to basic Java types automatically, if feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Test your ABAP remote function module with an SAP GUI via transaction code SE37 first.
If this test is successful and you get a different result if called from JCo with using the same parameter values, then I recommend to study SAP note [206068](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/206068) for possible reasons.

Also check your method `configureTableParameters`. I guess, `index` shall be a field index and not a row count. Your implementation will create far too many unnecessary rows. I assume you wanted to call `table.appendRow();` instead of `table.appendRows(index);`. Moreover, you maybe intended to fill the first field in the row with the value `"100"`, for which you would have to pass the index value `0` instead of `1` in this case.

Comment: I'm new to SAP.My intention is to get that particular partner records(partnerId=100).